# Finite groups $G$ such that every Galois extension of group $G$ is totally real

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, galois-theory

I was playing with Galois extensions of small degree while preparing the final exam for my course in Galois thoery, when the following question came up:

**Question.** Can we characterize the finite groups $G$ such that every Galois extension $L/\mathbb{Q}$ with Galois group $G$ is totally real ?

Note that every finite group $G$ with **odd** order satisfies this condition: if $\alpha$ is a primitive element of $L/\mathbb{Q}$, its minimal polynomial $f$ has odd degree, so it has a real root $\beta$. Now $\beta$ is also a primitive element of $L$, that is $K=\mathbb{Q}(\beta)$. Now, since $L$ is Galois it contains all the roots of $f$, so all the roots of $f$ are real.

I strongly suspect that the answer to the question above is related somehow to the representations of $G$, but I am not expert enough in representation theory to confirm this hunch.

I am happy to assume the the Galois inverse conjecture is true, so we don"t have to care about the existence of Galois extensions $L/\mathbb{Q}$ of given group $G$.

**Addendum.** I don't know any example of group having even-order satisfying the required property.

Comment: Do you know of any even-order groups with this property?  The closest thing I can think of is the quaternion group $Q_8$--if $L/\mathbb Q$ is a $Q_8$-field, then $L$ may be totally real or totally imaginary, but at least its quartic subfield (the fixed field of $-1 \in Q_8$) is totally real.  (Reason:  $-1$ is the only element of order $2$, so complex conjugation must be either $1$ or $-1 \in Q_8$, and thus everything fixed by $-1$ is real.)

Comment: For what it's worth, I just checked that [LMFDB](https://www.lmfdb.org/NumberField/?hst=List&galois_group=%5B8%2C1%5D&is_galois=yes&search_type=List) gives at least one real and one imaginary Galois number field with every possible Galois group of even order $\leq 20$.  (The first two numbers in the label indicate its degree and number of real embeddings.  Sometimes, as with the larger dihedral groups, you have to scroll through a few pages of results to find a real one.)

Comment: I don't know even-order examples. So maybe the answer is that $G$ must have odd order. For $Q_8$, there are imaginary Galois extensions of group $Q_8$ (the $Q_8$-extensions are all parametrized)

Comment: Any pair $(G,\sigma)$ of a group $G$ and a element (up to conjugacy) $\sigma$ with $\sigma^2=1$ is expected to arise as a Galois group with complex conjugation conjugate to $\sigma$. This is a generalization of the inverse Galois problem (IGP) but doesn't obviously follow from IGP. As a point of comparison, it's easy enough to find a totally real extension $K$ and a Galois $L/K$ with $G = \mathrm{L/K}$ and with complex conjugation at some infinite place to be $\sigma$, so there are not going to be any "local" obstructions. This would make any exception very strange.

Comment: In contrast, is true that IGP (for all finite groups) implies that any $G$ does occur as the Galois group of a totally real extension.